# Creating many-to-many relationships on a nested rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, many-to-many

I am trying to create Groups, Users and Memberships (the many-to-many relationships) simultaneously. People can add users to the group as they create it and then I want it to route through to a view of the group with all the members. I can get the users to be created and the current user's membership to save to the database. However I'm struggling to get the id for the freshly created User objects in order to save the new memberships.

## Group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_many :users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? or a[:number].blank? }
end
```

## Membership.rb

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :groups
  belongs_to :users
end
```

## User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
  belongs_to :group
end
```

## groups_controller.rb

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def new
    @group = Group.new

    3.times { @group.users.build }
  end

  def create 
    @group = Group.new(params[:group]) 
    @group.memberships.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
    logger.info @group.users

    @group.users.each do |x|
      @group.memberships.build(:user_id => x.id )
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@group, :notice => 'Success!') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end

  end
end
```

My form looks like this:

[image: The form creator]

Which is created by:

## views/groups/new.html.rb

```
<h1>New group</h1>

<%= form_for(@group) do |form| %>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Create a new group</legend>
  <%= render 'shared/group_error_messages', :object => form.object %>  
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= form.label :group_name %>
    <div class="input">
      <%= form.text_field :group_name %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="users">
    <div class="user">
      <%= form.fields_for :users, :url => {:action => 'new', :controller => 'users', :registered => false}, do |user_form| %>
      <%= render 'user', :user => user_form %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit :value => 'Create your group', :class => 'btn success'%>
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

## views/groups/_user.html.rb

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <%= user.label :name %>
  <div class="input">
    <%= user.text_field :name %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
  <%= user.label :number %>  
  <div class="input">
    <%= user.text_field :number %>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="clearfix" style="display:none">
  <%= user.label :password %>  
  <div class="input">
    <%= user.password_field :password, :value => newpass(6) %><!-- todo: fix this horrible hack -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" style="display:none">
  <%= user.label :registered %>  
  <div class="input">
    <%= user.text_field :registered, :value => false %> <!-- todo: fix this horrible hack -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" style="display:">
  <%= user.label :id %>  
  <div class="input">
    <%= user.text_field :id %> <!-- todo: fix this horrible hack -->
  </div>
</div>
```

So my main desire is to get this bit of code to find the User ids as they are created and then use those ids to build the memberships between the groups and users.

Thanks *very, very* much in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
has_many :users, :through => :memberships
has_many :users
```

is wrong, you can't have two or more associations with same name .

Try to do

```
has_many :users, :through => :memberships
has_many :members, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :user_id
```

and make corresponding changes in views and controllers . Like

```
form.fields_for : members
```

Comment: I get the error:    
    `ArgumentError (Unknown key(s): class):
    app/models/group.rb:26:in <class:Group>'
    app/models/group.rb:21:in <top (required)>'
    app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:24:in new'`

Comment: has_many :members, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :user_id

Comment: @pduey ... thanks for correction. I forgot that :) . Changing the answer accordingly .