# Joining Entity not saving in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, persistence, rails-activerecord

I am developing an application using Ruby on Rails, and in this application their is a many to many relationship that is not saving correctly. There are Users and each user can have many tasklists. These lists can be shared though so a tasklist can also have many users. Here are the models for my application.

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :task_list_users, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :task_lists, through: :task_list_users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_lists

    attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_token
    before_create :create_remember_token
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, 
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

**TaskList model**

```
class TaskList < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :task_list_users, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :task_list_users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

**TaskListUser**

```
class TaskListUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :task_list_id, :user_id
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :task_list
end
```

I am pretty sure that I have setup everything here correctly. The users will always be created first, and the tasklists will be added to users over time (or a tasklist can get users added). My problem is that I am saving a newly constructed TaskList that I build for a current_user User, and even if I save that constructed object to the database, the linking item is not saved.

I have confirmed that the TaskList is indeed being saved through the SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox.

The code I am using to actually create new tasklists for current_user is as follows.

```
class TaskListsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @task_list = current_user.task_lists.build(params[:task_list])
        if @task_list.save
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render "pages/home"
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end
end
```

I have gone through the previous questions here on SO, but the solutions that seem to have worked for everyone else are not working for me. All of the models mentioned above are configured as resources in the routes file, not sure if that really matters.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Try changing `@task_list.save` to `@task_list.save!`.  This will generate an exception if the task list does not save and you can examine the output for a clue to what's going on.

Comment: @Josh I just tried it and had no difference. No errors on the browser or listed in console where rails s was running

Comment: It looks to me that you never create the joining entity, or is that just my imagination? Did you try adding `@task_list_user = TaskListUser.new user_id: current_user.id, task_list_id: @task_list.id`. You also need to change the if to read `if @task_list.save && @task_list_user.save`. You should also destroy both in the else condition if they were saved.

Comment: According to everything I've read that shouldn't be needed. Declaring everything the way I have, I was under the impression it should work like I wrote as it is many to many through a linking element.

Comment: @Max I stand corrected, your code didn't work as you provided it, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266952/creating-many-to-many-relationships-on-a-nested-rails-form was a pretty similar fix and it worked. If you post as an answer I will accept your reply. Thank you!

Comment: It's ok. Glad you found an answer to you problem.